# Wordpress responsive images not picking the right image or orientation

Tags: php, wordpress, responsive-images

I have created custom image sizes in Wordpress to use with the responsive images plugin wordpress has installed by default. The images sizes i've added are:

```
add_image_size('portrait-case-study-xl', 1010, 1514, true);
add_image_size('portrait-case-study-lg', 505, 757, true);
add_image_size('portrait-case-study-md', 415, 622, true);
```

I'm then building the images from PHP using the metabox.io plugin and setting the loaded to be displayed as portrait-case-study-lg. I then load the srcset using the function from metabox.io and i've created my custom sizes where i want the images to change.

```
$images = rwmb_meta('su_project-featured-portrait-left', array('limit' => 1,
 'size' => 'portrait-case-study-lg'), $post->ID);

<a href="<?php echo $image['full_url']; ?>" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="<?php echo $image['width']; ?>x<?php echo $image['height'];?>">
                                    <img class="scene_element scene_element--fadeinup" src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" srcset="<?php echo esc_attr($image['srcset']); ?>" 
                                    sizes="(max-width:40em) 767px, (min-width: 40.063em) and (max-width: 64em) 455px, (min-width: 64.063em) and (max-width: 90em) 455px, (min-width: 90.063em) 505px, 100vw" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" >
                                </a>
```

The result looks like this:

```
<img class="scene_element scene_element--fadeinup"
 src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/chelsea-sw3-apartment-bedroom-505x757.jpg" srcset="http://localhost:8888/wp-
content/uploads/2017/11/chelsea-sw3-apartment-bedroom-300x200.jpg 300w, 
http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/chelsea-sw3-apartment-bedroom-768x512.jpg 768w, http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/chelsea-sw3-apartment-bedroom-1024x683.jpg 1024w, 
http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/chelsea-sw3-apartment-bedroom-355x238.jpg 355w, http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/chelsea-sw3-apartment-bedroom-955x637.jpg 955w,
 http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/chelsea-sw3-apartment-bedroom-940x627.jpg 940w" sizes="(max-width:40em) 767px, 
(min-width: 40.063em) and (max-width: 64em) 455px, 
(min-width: 64.063em) and (max-width: 90em) 455px, 
(min-width: 90.063em) 505px, 100vw" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image 
description">
```

The problem i have is it's now loading the landscape image with the width and height of 768x512 rather than loading the 505x757 image. Can anyone help me please? I'm very new to responsive images and when i thought i'd cracked it. It then starts to choose the wrong image :(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: update the answer with your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cracked it. I wasn't adding the custom image sizes into the Wordpress srcset :)